# Remove Hover Tip Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Small annoyance...

Does anyone know how to get rid of the tip that pops up on hover for CSS and JS? I couldn't find anything related in the settings file.
See screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I also struggled with this, and finally submitted an issue to the vscode repo.

Please try this:

1. On the menu bar: File>Preferences>User Settings
2. Add the following to your `settings.json`:

   ```json
   "editor.hover.enabled": false
   ```
3. Save your `settings.json` and your issue should be fixed.

Happy coding!

Comment: sometimes when we *need* the 'tip' to be shown though after a delay, the [following solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70547111/1042705) seemed to work for me

Answer (score 28):

From vscode docs [Hover display options](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_25#_hover-display-options):

> - use `editor.hover.enabled` to toggle the editor hover
> - use `editor.hover.delay` to customize the time until the hover is shown
> - use `editor.hover.sticky` to change if the hover should remain visible when moving the mouse over it.

The `editor.hover.sticky` is particularly useful if you still like the popup but don't like the default behavior that blocks your cursor. But bear in  mind it will make certain popups with which you need to interact (such as CSS color picker) useless.

Comment: it's not quite what the question was about, but delay was the setting I needed, I knew it had to exist! thanks :)

Answer (score 13):

Sometimes you want the tips to display, though after a delay, (sometimes, say in debugging etc. ) then the following seemed to work ( for me )

Press `cntrl + shift + P` and select **'Preferences: Open User Settings'** 
and set the value in **Editor > Hover: Delay** say, `2` seconds
[image]
(this will set a delay of **[entered value]** (milli)seconds, and not block the helper tip entirely)

*you can also go for **ctrl+k ctrl+i** to display the hover on-demand, but sometimes you don't want to go to keyboard when you're working with **mouse***

Ref: [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41115285/disable-tooltip-hint-in-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 2):

Updated 2022:

Since v1.54 VSCode has introduced a setting that allows fine-tuning the tooltip in HTML and CSS/SCSS/LESS.

`css.hover.documentation: false` if you want to disable displaying the documentation.

`css.hover.references: false` to disable the MDN reference only.

Change `css` to `html` will disable the above settings while editing in HTML.

reference: [VSCode update log version 1.54](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_54.md#hovers-in-csslessscss-and-html)

Answer (score 1):

Faced the Same Issue which is annoying.

As said above :

1. Go to `File->Preferences`
2. You will be under user settings.
3. Above that you have `search settings` bar.
4. Search for `Hover`
5. You will see `Editor-Hover:Enabled`

Disable it and you are good to go.