# How can I disable hover tooltip hints in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I disable the default tooltip hint message in VS Code that appears when I hover over things in the editor? It's annoying sometimes.

[image]

Comment: If they were just shifted over not blocking nearby text they'd be just fine!

Comment: I wish they were like Visual Studio, where they don't get in the way so much, and aren't selectable. The fact you can click and select on them, is what makes them annoying, for me.

Comment: Nothing worked for me from any of those suggestions, but I found the issue: HAD TO DISABLE PYLANCE. (then restart/reload) I still have intelisense suggestions when typing (whic i want) but got rid of those large popping boxes that were obstructing the view.

Comment: Disabling pylance worked like a charm for me. If you are unsure about what pylance do: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65475307/1195496

Comment: They're like swarming insects, always getting in your face, whenever you try to read or click anything.  Guillotine is too kind .  I set editor.quickSuggestionsDelay to an astronomically large number.  I turned off every single option I could find that 'suggests' or anything else like that, and they still kept coming.  Now I'm adding options that aren't listed but other people tell me about.

Answer (score 218, accepted):

> `editor.hover.enabled: false` in settings.json to Tooltip

Click on Edit in settings.json

*There are two panes*

**Default User Settings**

```
"editor.quickSuggestions": {
    "other": false,
    "comments": false,
    "strings": false
  }
```

**User Settings**

```
"editor.parameterHints.enabled": false,
"editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions": false,
"html.suggest.html5": false,
"editor.snippetSuggestions": "none",
```

This also can be done UI.

**Setting Snippet Suggestions : false**

Update August 2018 (version 1.27)

Goto `File=>Preference=>Settings`

`Text Editor => Suggestions`

Click on Edit in settings.json

```
"editor.parameterHints.enabled": false,
"editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions": false,
"html.suggest.html5": false,
```

Update your suggest options and save.

[image: New update option]

**Before August 2018**

Goto `File=>Preference=>User Settings`

You will find `settings.json`

```
// Configures if the built-in HTML language support suggests Angular tags and properties.
"html.suggest.angular1": false,

"html.suggest.ionic": false,

"html.suggest.html5": false,
```

Just find your language and set `suggest = false`

**Update**

> Setting to turn off ALL popups

```
"editor.parameterHints": false
```

[image: See the settings.json]

Comment: The first line in this answer is the only thing that works. That is the right answer.

Comment: i need the same tooltip turn off in visual studio. can anyone please guide for visual studio

Comment: additionally I've found that `"editor.hover.delay": 1000,` was enough for me.

Comment: As for me the most annoying thing of default hover behaviour - blocking mouse pointer from clicking text right above the hovered word. I became quite happy with the next setup: `"editor.hover.sticky": false`

Comment: Would love it if the hover was disabled unless I am holding down ctrl as that's when I am trying to follow references and usually wanting to learn more.

Answer (score 103):

```
"editor.hover.enabled": false,
```

is your bulletproof solution. Then you can use CTLR + K, CTLR + I.

Comment: I'm a big fan of this in addition to setting up caps lock as a hyper-key on my Mac. So then the hotkey would be capslock+i

Comment: @BigKids the annoy thing is after setting this for key stroke triggered hover, the hover is always there now unless you move your mouse... ESC does not close the hover

Comment: This works on Linux! However the default `ctrl + k` does not work and I had to map the "show definition preview hover" to `ctrl + k` manually and it works great now. Escape also works on Linux after invoking the hover with keyboard.

Comment: Thanks for the `Ctrl K`, `Ctrl I` shortcut... I remapped the "Show Hover" and "Debug: Show Hover" keyboard commands into `F1` (since `F1` initially showed the Command Palette), which will show the Hover tooltip on demand

Comment: This does not appear to work anymore. Neither does the delay even if used in the editor's settings. Weird. I really wish vscode did not try to do too much.

Comment: June 2023 on Linux: this solution works, and `esc` does close the tooltip invoked by `ctrl-K-I`

Answer (score 49):

To hide those hints you can just add `"editor.parameterHints": false` to your `settings.json`. Found the answer [in here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/14840#issuecomment-257931965).

Comment: No longer seems to be a valid value as of 2019. BigKids' answer was the only answer that worked for me, and has the added advantage that it still allows you to explicitly call the hints when you want to.

Answer (score 37):

In the menu, choose `File > Preferences > Settings`.
I find using a larger value for Editor > Hover: Delay (search for "delay" in the settings search bar) does the trick for me. Its default is 300ms. This doesn't address the desire to actually eliminate the tooltips, but having them only appear after, say, 2 seconds, reduces the visual clutter quite a bit for me.

Comment: Thank you. I've set everything to false, but tooltips are always here. Setting the delay to a larger value is the only effective solution I've found :)

Comment: Where is Editor, even? These Settings on VS Code are rightly effing me off. How do I know which of the suggestion options relate to the element that pops up when I hover on a css block (I'm using svelte which combines the css in the same file)?

Comment: Thanks for this. I like having the tooltip available when I need it but the default 300 ms value makes it appear every time I try to set my cursor somewhere. ANNOYING!

Comment: Thanks from me as well - The hover hints are useful, but as they stay visible even when you haver the tooltip itself: the line above becomes uneditable without moving the cursor unnaturally.

Comment: This is the better answer. I set it to 900ms.

Answer (score 30):

I'm using Visual Studio Code v1.63.0 and in Settings I searched for "hover" and, among other things, found "Editor > Hover: Delay" and "Editor > Hover: Enabled".  Unchecking the latter will disable the hover.  However, I personally find them useful but they're displayed too quickly so I increased ""Editor > Hover: Delay" from "300" to "5000"

[image]

Comment: Lifesaver. It was impossible for me to do multiline selections with my mouse!

Comment: Thanks.  Was driven demented by this feature

Comment: @darrell What theme are you using?

Comment: Gruvbox Dark Soft

Comment: Thanks it worked, in latest or newer version of vsc, this option is mentioned under 'preferences ->Online services settings'. Alternatively you can add the line "editor.hover.delay": 3000,  (as it is with quotes) in user settings and specify your desired value instead of 3000.

Answer (score 24):

On version 1.27.2, I found that only this parameter disabled all the tooltips: `"editor.hover.enabled": false`.

Comment: Someone already posted this answer here two days before yours.

Answer (score 16):

Simple way that no one here has mentioned: Code → Preferences → Settings. Search for "hover". Uncheck the checkbox where it says "Editor > Hover: Enabled".

Answer (score 16):

**Cntrl + shift + P** -> **Prefences: Open Settings (JSON)**

```
"editor.parameterHints": false,
"editor.hover.enabled": false
```

i had to do both of these.

Comment: Thanks for the shortcut, sometimes you're too lazy to think of _' where the setting is ? '_

Comment: And what is difference for the two? In Python, the first one isn't color coded and can be triggered within parenthesis for a callable; the latter is color coded and can be triggered from the function/method name. Otherwise, both of these display the same information

Answer (score 7):

Here's the noob version, assuming you know little about VS Code (like me).

Windows.
VS Code version: 1.37.1

1. While in VS Code:

   press F1 then type "settings" or "preferences" - then click "Preferences: Open User Settings"

   - or -

   from top menu: File>Preferences>Settings

   - or -

   hotkey: ctrl+,
2. in the settings pane, type "hover" (no need to press "enter")
3. the settings pane should display the hover settings immediately
4. Uncheck "Editor › Hover: Enabled"

   [hover disable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrAm2.png)

Rockstar Version: edit the JSON like a balla

1. F1 then type "Open Settings (JSON)"
    
   -or- 

   navigate to settings JSON file and open in VS Code

   https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settings-file-locations
2. Add this to JSON file (within curly braces, INCLUDE quotes): "editor.hover.enabled": false

   Note: each line needs a comma after it. If you add to top, put a comma after this line. If you add to bottom, add a comma after the previous line.
3. Don't forget to save!

   [what JSON looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJ08V.png)

If you're new to coding, those tooltips can come in handy. You may want instead to just DELAY their appearance as Logan suggested.

click here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53512394/8623576
or simply scroll up! :)

Note: I appreciate others have posted almost the EXACT same answer but, as I mentioned, this is the NOOB version that assumes the user has little/no experience with VS Code.

Answer (score 3):

for Versions 1.31+ this one line did it for me:

```
"editor.parameterHints.enabled": false
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to the settings gear wheel in the bottom left hand corner, then go to Settings and search "hover". Uncheck the "Controls whether the hover is shown" box.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not looking for disable and as mentioned by user: **Darrell Brogdon** above, if you want to delay the hover time of tooltip as solution then simply add the below line in user settings with your desired time value.
replace value 3000 as per your need.
Note: hover settings are moved in Online Services Settings in newer versions, hence you might not be able to find it with search 'hover' in user settings.

```
      // modify in Preferences --> Settings or settings.json

      "editor.hover.delay": 3000,
```

Answer (score 1):

Running with v1.72.1. noticed in the tooltip window there is an 'x' in the upper right corner for a close,  clicking it. It worked and seems to have persisted my desire to dismiss them.

Thinking about it, don't see a way to get them back if someone might actually want them back.