# How to remove "floating panels" when coding w/ vscode?

Tags: ide, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to get rid of this floating panels when typing code on vscode (screenshot attached).
I'm guessing I should add/edit something to my config file, but can't figure out which is the command.

Any help please?

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable tooltip hint in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41115285/disable-tooltip-hint-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: You're right, that answer solved my problem. Ty.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable tooltip hint in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41115285/disable-tooltip-hint-in-visual-studio-code)