# VS Code: How to disable function hover pop-up without disabling anything else, and preferably to only activate on demand with a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Haven't figured out how to do this yet after multiple web and Settings searches, and not finding this asked already here.

I tried "editor.hover": false, but it just puts a green squiggly underline under it saying it's an unknown configuration setting.

If I make a function call in say a .php file, then inadvertently hover over it, it pops up an un-called-for box obscuring what I'm reading or blocking what I meant to click.

I'd like to be able to stop this and only have it activate on-demand with a keyboard shortcut, but without disabling other features.

Comment: `"editor.hover": false` is in my User Settings, and I've already saved and restarted, but the box still pops up on hover showing a basically useless "mini" reference: https://imgur.com/a/uvaHz

If I hold Ctrl while hovering, it shows an expanded reference which is at least useful: https://imgur.com/bYLwHuV

All I want is for the pop-up to only show on demand.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable tooltip hint in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41115285/disable-tooltip-hint-in-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the only combination that worked for me:

```
"editor.parameterHints": false,
"editor.hover": false,
"editor.quickSuggestions": false,
```

Answer (score 2):

The only setting that works on version 1.29.1 is:

```
"editor.hover.enabled": false,
```