# Disable annoying tooltip in the side bar of Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

This annoying tooltip hides some parts of the side bar (see the screen shot bellow) and I want to disable it.

I checked the options in settings JSON file, there seems to be no way in there.

Is there any way to disable this tooltip?

EDIT: Please note that this question is about tooltip from side bar, not about tooltips from editor window.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable tooltip hint in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41115285/disable-tooltip-hint-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: No, actually not, my question is about tooltip from side bar, not about tooltips from editor window.

Comment: You will need to submit a feature request on their GitHub repo.

Comment: @duke636 Did you ever find a way to disable this?

Comment: I don't think they're interested in fixing it. I think they're going to destroy vscode in the end.