# Get rid of the helper window

Tags: visual-studio-code

I can seem to get rid of the helper text.  Where is that setting? I dont want to see the helper window with the ajax stuff.

[image: HelperCode]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable tooltip hint in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41115285/disable-tooltip-hint-in-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the menu bar: File>Preferences>User Settings
Add the following to your settings.json:

"editor.hover": false

Comment: You are a lifesaver...What about the dropdown of possible variables to autocomplete?  if i type $va  I get a hover if all variables that might match va

Comment: Turn off intellisense - Menu:  Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> All Languages [or specific language] -> General -> Statement completion