# Is it possible to change the position of parameter hints and suggestions widgets in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'd like to change the position of the Visual Studio Code hint tooltip that is useful, but horribly placed sometimes. (covering the code, jumping all over the place while typing, etc.)

I don't know if it would help, but right now I'd like to fix the hints position to the top right corner of the editor. (Or it could adapt to the situation and be at top right or bottom right depending on where I am typing)

Would look for something like:

```js
hintPanelPositionMode: 'fixed'
hintPanelPositionPlacement: 'right'
```

or edit some settings somewhere in pseudo CSS style

```css
.hint-panel {position: 'fixed'; top: 0; right: 0}
```

As a side note: it is somewhat related to what is explained in this question [How can I disable hover tooltip hints in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41115285/disable-tooltip-hint-in-visual-studio-code)

Is this possible currently?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of now there is no way to move the `parameterHints` position in VS Code.

There is an open issue on this matter you can find here : https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/15667

I actually just suggested there something like what you are proposing.
Let's hope they will implement something to fix this soon, because that's really annoying.

In the meantime you can hide it completely by adding to your settings :

`"editor.parameterHints.enabled": false`

That's not ideal to remove it completely though, up to you.

Comment: how does the linked issue ticket address this problem of hover positioning?

Comment: It didn’t, and now is closed and locked, that’s the problem. You do realize that’s a 4 years old issue, things might have changed (hopefully) since then.

Answer (score 0):

For suggestions and parameter hints, see the following issue tickets:

- [Allow parameter hints and completion documentation to appear in a docked panel instead of floating over the code #149270](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/149270)
- [Create an option to position the intellisense parameter info top or bottom. #33752](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/33752)

I suggest that you give those issue ticket a thumbs up to show support for them. You can also subscribe to them to get notified about discussion and progress. Please avoid making noisy comments there like ones that just consist of "+1" / "bump".

---

As an FYI, for hovers, there is `editor.hover.above`, which defaults to `true`, and is described as follows:

> Prefer showing hovers above the line, if there's space.

Note that there are other settings that can help mitigate things that some people find as annoyances with hovers: `editor.hover.delay`, and `editor.hover.sticky` (whether to keep hover visible when you mouseover it).

You may also be interested in [VSCode: How do I open the documentation (ala `show hover`) in another pane?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61324685/11107541).