# VSCode: How do I open the documentation (ala `show hover`) in another pane?

Tags: julia, visual-studio-code

**Update**: This is not currently supported. I have filed a feature request [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/95784). Be sure to upvote it if you like to see this implemented.

---

I like to be able to see the documentation of the symbol at cursor using a keyboard shortcut. I know of the command `editor.action.showHover`, but I can't scroll that popup's contents using the keyboard. In fact, I prefer to have a documentation pane open at the right side that just shows the docs for anything the cursor is on.

Here is a screenshot of `show hover`:
[image]

Comment: The "open in pane" idea is already a feature request on GitHub -- you'll make a bigger impact if you find that one first and comment / upvote there, rather than start a new FR.  I don't know which thread, or I'd link it here, but do an internet search for words like "intellisense hover tooltip position github vscode"  and you shoudl find a bunch of threads.

Comment: historically related: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/51253

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Have a look at the [Docs View](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bierner.docs-view) extension.  I think it does what you want:

> VS Code extension that displays hover documentation in the sidebar or
> panel.

[image: Docs View demo]

Comment: This is awesome! I've been looking for this since VS Code was first released. This is the feature that made me switch to IntelliJ. The formatting of the docs in VS Code is still ugly and you have to click rather than the docs updating on mouse hover, but this is a huge step in the right direction. Big thank you to the author of this extension and Mark for suggesting it.

Answer (score 6):

This is not possible natively in VSCode as of 2020,
but there is a lot of chatter on GitHub about the Intellisense suggestion UI.

If this is a feature you're interested in, you can add your vote
(click thumbs up in the first post of the thread) or your voice here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/33752

In the meanwhile, you can make the suggestion box transparent   https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/22439#issuecomment-600855615
so at least you can see the code it covers.

Also related, but not identical:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/15667
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/30797