# How to enable hover in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, hover

When I go to the function, I want to see its references links and navigate to them. In my Sublime Text it is working properly but I want to make proper in my VS Code also.

[image: Screenshot showing the hover in Sublime with "Definition" and "References" sections containing links]

Comment: very very tempted to close as a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41115285/how-can-i-disable-hover-tooltip-hints-in-vs-code

Answer (score 5):

### Enable the language extension

I fixed this by going to **Extensions**, typing `@builtin`, scrolling to my language extension in **Features** list (**Typescript and Javascript** item) and enabling it:

[image: Screenshot showing how to get to Extensions on Mac]

[image: Screenshot showing "TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features" in the Features list]

For some reasons the extension was disabled in the list (even though the docs say it's enabled by default).

[image: Screenshot showing the extension now enabled]

Source: [alexdima's comment from 4 Dec 2019 on GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/85846#issuecomment-561649920)

Answer (score 5):

I recently had the same issue for like a week and I was going crazy, then I discovered that there is a setting for it, which I don't remember disabling but anyways it fixed the problem.

Go to your VSCode settings (`settings.json`) and set `editor.hover.enabled` to `true`.

```json
{
  "editor.hover.enabled": true
}
```

Otherwise, if you like UI setting stuff, search for "*hover enabled*" or `editor.hover.enabled` in your settings and make sure it is enabled.

[image: setting image]

Answer (score 1):

The feature you are referencing is known as **IntelliSense** in VSCode, which is enabled by default on versions 1.3 and above.

The languages supported out of the box are **JavaScript** and **TypeScript**.

So, if you need code-IntelliSense for other languages you'll have to install [extensions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/vscode) for the specific languages.

**See image below for IntelliSense support**

[image: Screenshot showing IntelliSense explanation/demo]

Answer (score 0):

if you are using /** */ comments on C++ i found out that disabling this option may help seeing them in the hover:
[simplify structured comments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E23yd.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).