# How to close this function prompt in VSCode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

[image] Can someone tell me how to turn off this function prompt which labelled by red lines? I spent a night not finding it.

Comment: Does the solution here suffice your requirement: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41115285/disable-tooltip-hint-in-visual-studio-code

Comment: Thank you for your help, but our problems were not the same.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to turn it off:

[image]