# Is there a way to turn off hover for certain functions in VSCode?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, visual-studio-code

In VSCode, I have the hovers enabled that show me the docstrings of the functions (etc.) I use. I appreciate that functionality. However, some of the hovers get annoying with time. First and foremost, the one for `print`. I never need it, and it is huge. It is particularly annoying in Jupyter notebooks, where I use `print` quite often.

Hence, my question: Is there a way to disable the hover for certain functions specifically?

I have looked through the VSCode documentation but haven't found anything.

Comment: It seems like there are ways to turn off tooltip altogether, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41115285/disable-tooltip-hint-in-visual-studio-code), but I don't think there is a way to selectively toggle that option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to turn off hovers on select items.