# Settings for Hover Hints in Haxe language support in VSC

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, haxe

Sometimes the hints that popup like the image shown (https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Mx73.png) are useful, but many times they just get in the way. Is there a setting in the Haxe extension that controls when and how these hint popups appear? Is there a setting in VSC the the extension uses to control that?

I am using VSC v1.44.2 for macOS and Haxe extension v2.19.5.

Comment: maybe this will be of help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41115285/disable-tooltip-hint-in-visual-studio-code

Comment: There's a Haxe-specific setting to remove doc comments from signature help popups so they don't take up as much space, but other than that, there's only VSCode-wide settings.