# VSCode settings for documentation

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, settings

[image]

VSCode shows me the mini-doc while I type whereas I want it to be displayed only when I hover over a word. How do I change my settings to accomplish this? I have python and pylance extensions installed.

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove the hint from VS Code look [in here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode), in short:

To hide them you can just add `"editor.parameterHints": false` to your **[settings.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_creating-user-and-workspace-settings).**

I also found a very cool Stack Overflow answer:

### [@Eldho](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41115383/13903942)

Doing this may turn of all hints completely though, hope this helped.