# How to enable again the tooltip/hint in VSC?

Tags: visual-studio-code

My VSC shows the wavy underlines when something's wrong with my code, but **does not** display the hint overlay when I hover my mouse on it.

This happens whatever the language used (from CSS to Typescript) and whatever the type of irregularity (e.g. notice, warn, danger)

I'd say that's a setting I may have changed at some point, but can't find which one. Any idea?

**More details:**

- I *do* have the message displayed in the Problems tab besides to the Terminal, but it forces me to switch from tab to tab ;
- I do have other overlays like autocomplete/autosuggest ;
- No extensions in my setup could have led to that situation (only a few installed, widely downloaded, nothing fancy or dodgy).

**Actual behavior (nothing happens):**

[image: Nothing shows up when hovering the wavy error]

**Expected behavior (from google images)**

[image: Expected]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. Go to File > Preferences > Settings.
2. Search for 'hover.enabled' (See below photo).
3. Toggle it.
4. If your editor still does not pick up the change, close all tabs, close all VSCode windows, and reopen it.
5. If it's still not working, try uninstalling VSCode and reinstalling it (make sure you don't have setting sync on).

Also, this question has been answered in at least one other place ([Disable tooltip hint in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41115285/disable-tooltip-hint-in-visual-studio-code))

[image: VSCode hover enabled toggle]