# How to disable hints while typing on vscode

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

While I'm typing, I constantly get these pop-up explanation windows which are extremely annoying. How can I disable it?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply press `ctrl+space` key to enable or disable this suggestion.

You can also follow this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41115285/10157127)

Comment: "editor.parameterHints": false


This code block provided in the question you mentioned did the trick in the corresponding language's field. Thanks...

Comment: Not sure why this is the accepted answer and Lars' answer isn't getting some love.
The answer here is not an answer to the question.

Answer (score 2):

This adjust did the trick

```
"editor.quickSuggestions": {
        "other": false,
  },
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.
A slight tweak as of 2023, the setting is "off" rather than false.