# Disable hover hint for python keyword in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I want to disable hover hint for python keyword (for example import), but preserve linter message. How can I do this?
[image]

UPDATE: settings.json

```
{
  "python.pythonPath": "venv/bin/python",
  "python.formatting.provider": "black",
  "python.linting.enabled": true,
  "python.linting.pylintEnabled": false,
  "python.jediEnabled": false,
  "python.linting.flake8Enabled": true,
  "python.languageServer": "Jedi",
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but it's a little weird, I can not get the hint of `import`. Have you configured something in the settings.json and which python interpreter have you selected?

Comment: @Steven-MSFT it appears by default. I now have version 1.61.2 (downloaded from github assets). Previously I had latest 1.63 (pylint messages don't appear in 1.63).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's provided by the `Jedi` Language Server, You can take `Pylance` instead of it:

```
"python.languageServer": "Pylance",
```

Comment: it works, but now vscode asks to install `pylance` on every start, but i guess it's a separate issue

Comment: Great answer, I wasn't aware since I've been using Pylance as default for ages, but it had switched to Jedi while debugging inside a Docker container!

Answer (score 0):

quick solution for Mac OS:
Go to

`Settings` of VS code --> `type 'Hover" in search settings box` --> Uncheck box of `Editor > Hover: Enabled`
This is also preserve linter message if any syntax error.

There is already solution provided, please refer below URL

[Disable tooltip hint in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41115285/disable-tooltip-hint-in-visual-studio-code)

Please have a look for screenshot: [image]

Comment: It will disable all tooltip messages. I want to preserve messages from linter