# How can i turn off this information box in vscode's flutter extention?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

Whenever I create a widget, this box opens, and I don't need it. How to turn it off?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable tooltip hint in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41115285/disable-tooltip-hint-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: Nope. I guess I have to turn it off from dart extension settings, but I can't find anything regarding my problem in extension settings.

Answer (score 2):

Search for parameterHints in Setting and uncheck it [take a look at this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLZhr.png)