# Can't see intellisense in studio code for angular rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs

Im following a tutorial for Angular and in the video lessons the professor is now explaining RXJS. Problem is when I try to see a description for a method i see nothing

IE my code:

```
range(1, 200).pipe(
   filter(x => x % 2 === 0),
   map(x => x * x)).subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

When i hover the range method with my cursor i see just this:

```
(alias) range(start: number, count?: number | undefined): Observable<number> (+1 overload)import range
```

The professor instead has the description as well.. For the same code if he hovers the range method with his cursor he sees:

```
(alias) range(start: number, count?: number | undefined): Observable<number> (+1 overload)import range
Creates an Observable that emits a sequence of numbers within a specified range.
<span class="informal">Emits a sequence of numbers in a range.</span>
```

I tried googling and searching in the visual studio code marketplace if i was missing and extension or something but can't find anything. Can you help? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Im using the same version. 1.77.3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable tooltip hint in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41115285/disable-tooltip-hint-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: it does not. In fact that's the opposite of what i want